# Using twitter login in ios

Tags: ios5, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Twitter handle from Twitter Framework in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407551/getting-twitter-handle-from-twitter-framework-in-ios)

I am fairly new to iOS development and in the very beginning i require to integrate twitter in my app. i went over at least a hundred tutorials for it but most of them showed how to tweet from my app.
what i specifically want is to be able to access user information like username, email id, password and profile image. 
if anyone has a link to regarding tutorial, please provide it at the earliest!
thanks.

Comment: The above-linked question shows how to grab the username, but there's no legitimate reason you'd ever want to get the user's password and email address, so Twitter's not going to give you that information.

Comment: [Here](http://dummycode.com/b/3) is a great post on integrating Twitter API with iOS.